Can I grapple someone's mouth shut if they're 2 inches (50.8 mm) tall and I'm 3.3866 mm tall?
First, I'm going to answer why I'm 3.3866 mm tall to answer the foreseeable questions I'll get from this. I'm in a campaign where the party was shrunk down 30 times, making 5 feet equivalent to 2 inches. I joined during session 2 and didn't know about the shrinking situation, and got permission to be 4 inches tall, and the DM forgot to tell me about being shrunk. I did the math, and 4 inches divided by 30 is 3.3866 mm. The DM confirmed that I am 3.3866 mm now. With that out of the way, let's get back to the question.
I'm playing as a chaotic good fairy barbarian, and we found some mushrooms on the side of the road, and 2 of my teammates, the wizard and the cleric, decided to use the paladin as a live test to see what the mushroom does. They were able to pin him down, but couldn't beat the DC to force feed him the mushroom. I made a medicine check to make sure it wasn't poisonous, and after confirming that it wasn't poisonous, and with some egging on from the DM, I helped force feed him the mushroom, as that sounds on-par for the course for a chaotic good character, rolling 19+3 in a strength check.
Turns out it was a hallucinogen called rainbow road (yes, that one. Yes, he did see Bowser and hear Mario kart music). This made him high for 12 days, and we couldn't sleep with him making so much noise. While we were brainstorming how to shut him up, I suggested that I grapple his mouth shut. The DM said no because that sounded painful, but now I'm wondering if it would work if the DM didn't say I wasn't going to do that.
I understand that this could be painful, but I stand by the belief that it would be less painful than what we ended up doing, that being knocking him out. I know this could be considered rude to the player, but the DM was the one who wanted him to be high in game, and said he was being too loud for us to sleep.

What size category are you all in relation to each other? Is the Paladin considered a Large creature and you a Small creature?

Technically, we're probably all tiny despite the very noticeable size difference between us, as all of us are below 2 feet tall @pyrotexhnical

For the purposes of grappling, character sizes are generally relative to each with regards to the campaign. If you ever saw Dimension 20's Tiny Heist, all the characters were super tiny (various toys and fey creatures), but relative to each other were all Medium; for comparison's sake, the child who played with the toys was effectively beyond Gargantuan and was probably more like a god.

@Pyrotechnical Probably tiny-medium then, me being tiny and him being medium. I know I can't grapple the whole creature according to grapple rules, but I wasn't sure about grappling part of the creature rather than the whole creature.

What did I do wrong this time?

"I helped force feed him the mushroom, as that sounds on-par for the course for a chaotic good character." Drugging someone against their will just for fun isn't any flavor of good.

@Shivers should I have instead taken it out of his mouth and force fed it to the other 2 who were trying to force feed it to him due to my barbaric nature?

@Tasi Hard for me to say what you should've done. Personally, I would've just tried to prevent them from drugging the paladin (or, more likely, had an out-of-character discussion about PvP and character autonomy). If I was the paladin, I probably would've left the game entirely. I think alignment should be used descriptively ("my character behaves like X, so they have alignment Y") rather than prescriptively ("my character has alignment Y, so they would behave like X"), but the specifics should depend on your character and the tone of the game.

Only with DM permission
Per your response to comments the paladin's size, relative to yours, is Medium and yours is Tiny. Per the grappling rules:

The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach.

There are no rules that I'm aware of that specifically allow you to grapple specific parts of a larger creature. Such rules might exist in specific modules or for specific character builds, but to my knowledge the general rules regarding grappling don't permit you to initiate a grapple with someone more than 1 size larger than you.
That said, if the DM says you can try, then you can try.

Alright, just wanted to make sure, thanks.

You're too small
As Pyrotechnical points out, you can't grapple someone who is that much larger than your character.
Grappling can't do that
When you grapple someone, it means they can't move away from you.  It doesn't have any other effects.  Most notably, they can still spellcast, which means they can speak freely.
If your DM allowed you to "grapple someone's mouth shut", it would have major implications for game balance, because you could immediately do that to any enemy spellcaster.
Your DM might allow you to gag someone
Even if you grapple someone's mouth shut, your character isn't going to be able to sleep while doing that.  What you want is to gag them, and probably also manacle them so they can't remove the gag.
Unfortunately you basically can't put manacles on an unwilling target -- see this question for more detail.  You'd have to knock them unconscious first.
It's interesting to see the variety of ways people play this game
I've played in lots of games, and in basically any of them, attempting to forcibly restrain another player character and then feed them unknown drugs would immediately result in the player saying:
"What's wrong with you people?  D&D is about roleplaying being a group of heroes, not playing juvenile pranks on each other!  I'm quitting the game, and I'm never playing with you again."
It's eye-opening to see that there are players who are interacting with the game in such a different way.

Yeah, that probably wasn't the best decision making on my part. It just seemed like the DM wanted this to happen, so I didn't give that much thought after I made sure it wasn't poisonous

@v2blast, can you link me to an explainer or style guide that talks about why we can't use single-# headers?  Naively, it seems like the right solution here should be that stackexchange should make sure that their single-# headers should be usable by accessible readers.

@DanB: I agree, but in the absence of that, using ## headers for answer headings makes more sense, since the question title is the <h1> element on the page. I think this answer to "Use real headers instead of fake headers" and the answer to What are some consensus recommendations for screenreader readability formatting? are the only references about this that we have on RPG Meta.
